# Linux: Crontab Job without Interfering with Sys Admin's Jobs?

Tags: linux, email, cron

I need to create a new crontab job in a Redhat Linux environment. I have sudo access to that but I don't think I can do everything on that system--some higher level sys admins, for example, disable any firewall changes I make.

So here is my crontab command:

```
crontab e
```

and that brings up a screen like:

```
33 2 * * * /usr/bin/cu-firewall update > /dev/null 2>&1
30 1 * * * /root/update_atbi_website > /dev/null
0  4 * * * /home/prov356/scripts/opnforumbackup
```

I want to not send email and I have done it successfully in my local VM:

```
MAILTO=""
# execute 15 minute
*/15 * * * * perl /db_xenia/pl/get_usgs.pl
```

Question: If I were to append the above to the existing crontab info will it prevent sending of emails to the sys admin too? I don't want to get into trouble! Perhaps, I could append /dev/null after my Perl commands?

Thanks.

Comment: You don't need root priviledge to run `crontab -e`

Comment: alright, so I should just log in and not sudo and do the crontab -e? Will it run as expected without being setup by a root?

Comment: Why don't you try? BTW your question is off-topic here.

Comment: So was 'superuser' the right forum?

Comment: Okay, I created a crontab without sudo and got confirmation was installed. Should I restart the cron engine? Or is it effective already? Thanks.

Comment: please please please read the man page for cron and crontab

Comment: Yes, I should have. Things went smooth on my VM but I didn't expect that in the actual server; anyway, I have enabled the cron job and it is running without anything needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind: Per @Basile's comment, I didn't need to be sudo. So I logged in as non-sudo and ran `crontab -e`; this time there were no sys admin entries. So I simply entered my own configs, saved, and the cronjob seems to be running fine.

Thanks.